# Argis symbology: selection in a string?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

I want to change symbology of one layer in ArcGIS 10.3. I want to have two types of symbology, but the field I want to use is string and there are more than 500 combinations, for example:

```
a1_b1_b2
a2_b2
b1
a1_b2_c3
...
a1_m6
...
a1_x1
```

I would like to have all the strings containing "x1" with another type of symbolgy, but how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind creating an additional field, you could do that and fill the new field with the two combinations.

You could use the field calculator to create a "pre-logic script code" and use Python (or VB Script) to check if the 500 combinations field contains 'x1' or whatever and write the appropriate value in the new field if the condition is true.

Your symbology would then be based on the new field.